# Default MS Word to single page view

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, default-settings

Remember the good old days when MS Word defaulted to single page view when you'd open a document? I do. I prefer that, because I want to focus on what I'm working on, not what's 30 lines away from that.

I'm using MS Word 365, and whenever I open a document it defaults to 2-page view. I then have to sigh, squeeze a stress ball, and adjust the View setting to 1-page view to get the view I want. I'd like to set 1-page view as default. Is there a way to do that in MS Word 365?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Word has no setting to specify a default "open" view for
all documents.
This means that documents open at the view mode that was used when the
document was originally saved.

To force the issue, a VBA macro is required. The macro, named `AutoOpen`,
needs to be saved in the `Normal.dotm` template.

Here is the macro:

```
Public Sub AutoOpen()
    ThisDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.PageColumns = 1
End Sub
```

To always open at 100% zoom, add this line inside the macro:

```
    ThisDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Zoom.Percentage = 100
```

For more information see the article [Writing a Macro from Scratch](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T006821_Writing_a_Macro_from_Scratch.html).

Answer (score 9):

Very late answer but I find it annoying when the question is either not answered correctly or stated that it can't be done. No code needed here.

1. Open Word and go to File > Open
2. Navigate to `%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates` or `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Templates` (whichever exists)
3. Open Normal.dot or Normal.dotm, whichever exists
4. Go to View and select "One Page" in the ribbon under the "Zoom" section
5. This might change your zoom so make sure it is at 100% or whatever you wish
6. Save
7. Close
8. Problem gone

Comment: The location of the templates folder and normal.dotm is located in c:/users/name/appdata/roaming/microsoft/templates in my case.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2016 (365), in the View Ribbon, select Print View.

Then Words opens to just one page. I have this set and always see just one page when opening Word.

[image]

I also disable the Start Screen for all Office 365 Apps, but I do not think this affects how Word opens the view. It does simplify things to uncheck Start Screen. Word, Options, General, near the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

These steps worked for me too, with the exception that I'm also using office 365 on one drive.

I had to navigate to a slightly differt folder;

`C:\Users\(User name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

There I found `Normal.dotm`
I made a back up copy of it. Then I tinkered with it. It wouldn't let me save over it. So I saved it with the name "`Normal.dotm.docx`" I then deleted the original file and deleted the Docx off the end of the new one I made.

It seems to be working now.

--original --

- Open word and go to file>open
- Navigate to c:/users/name/appdata/local/microsoft/templates
- Open the normal.dot or normal.dots depending on your version
- go to view and select "one page" in the ribbon under "zoom"
  This might change your zoom so make sure it is a 100% or whatever you wish
- Save
- close

Problem gone

Answer (score 0):

I added the "one page" and "100% zoom" buttons to the quick access bar, this seems to be the best way of dealing with it besides using macros.